# In a SQL query, getting only 30 characters before and after pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query like :

```
SELECT name,user from table where user LIKE '%bob%'
```

I would like, instead of having all the field displayed, to get only 30 characters before and after "bob".

If it's not possible then only the 30 characters after the "bob" pattern.

Example : field contains aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc123456789**bob**ppppppppppoooooooooouuuuuuuuuuyyyyyyyyyy" , then, the output would be :

- the 30 previous characters before "bob" pattern
- "bob", the pattern
- and the 30 characters following "bob", the pattern

So in this case the output would be "bbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc123456789**bob**ppppppppppoooooooooouuuuuuuuuu"

Thank you for your help

(the DBMS is mysql if it helps)

Comment: what do you mean with 30 chars .. update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: and are you trying to get a block of data before and after or specifically 30 characters?

Comment: You can use 'trim' function, not clear from your question which field you want to use it on?

Comment: If you don't want all fields displayed, don't use `SELECT *`, just list the fields that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LOCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to find the index of a substring, thereby emulating `LIKE`-like behavior.

It is case-insensitive if the collation is, and the strings are non-binary (i.e. `(var)char`, not `(var)binary`).

```
SELECT 
    `otherColumn`,
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('bob', yourColumn) < 30 
            THEN SUBSTRING(yourColumn, 1, LOCATE('bob', yourColumn) + CHAR_LENGTH('bob') + 30)
        ELSE
            SUBSTRING(yourColumn, LOCATE('bob', yourColumn) - 30, CHAR_LENGTH('bob') + 60)
    END AS `Text`,
    `anotherColumn`
FROM
    `table`
WHERE 
    LOCATE('bob', yourColumn) IS NOT NULL
```

This query, inspired by [mysql select content around keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258953/mysql-select-content-around-keyword), finds records with at least one occurrence of "bob" in `yourColumn`, and returns thirty characters around the first instance of that word - if there's enough text.

If "bob" is closer than thirty characters to the start of the column's value, the query returns the start of the string up till thirty characters after the first occurrence of "bob".

You might want to stick this into a parameterized query or stored procedure.

If you happen to want to build a full-text search engine, consider using existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using the charindex function. Charindex returns the starting position (so an INT datatype) of the specified string.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) =   'abc123456789012345678901234567890bob123456789012345678901234567890abc'
DECLARE @FindBob INT         = CHARINDEX('bob', @string)


SELECT String   =   @string , 
       FindBob  =   @FindBob , 
       FinalString  =   SUBSTRING(@string, @FindBob-30, 63)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern ("bob") can occure only once in the string you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split the string:

```
select 
    substring_index(user, 'bob',  1) as part1,
    substring_index(user, 'bob', -1) as part2
from some_table
where user like '%bob%';
```

To limit the substrings to 30 characters you can use the `left()` and `right()` functions:

```
select 
    right(substring_index(user, 'bob',  1), 30) as part1,
    left (substring_index(user, 'bob', -1), 30) as part2
from some_table
where user like '%bob%';
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/XDR12496